# How to convert const void* to unsigned char*?

Tags: c++

What C++ casts is the C cast using in order to convert from a const void* to a unsigned char*?

```
auto ucharptr = (unsigned char*)const_void_ptr;
```

Comment: Perhaps useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: I saw this and I thought that it uses const_cast first to get rid of the const and then a static_cast to convert into a unsigned char*. But this doesn't seem like the case

Comment: @BobBobby What makes you say it doesn't seem like the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the C++ casting operator and you need **two** of them: one to remove the `const` and another one to cast to your pointer type:

```
auto ucharptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<void*>(const_void_ptr));
```

Comment: Can I not use a static_cast instead after taking off the const with const_cast?

Comment: Technically speaking - yes, you can use `static_cast` as well. I prefer to be explicit about my intents. If I'm "reinterpreting" a pointer I'd rather state that fact in the code I'm writing. See the "static_cast vs. reinterpret_cast" (Google it) for more info.

Comment: @BobBobby Yes, you can. A cast to/from `void` pointee is `static`.

Comment: Except the Standard says it's equivalent to a `const_cast` then `static_cast`, not `const_cast` then `reinterpret_cast`.  Casting from a `void*` via `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` is equivalent on most platforms, but isn't required to be.

Comment: As I really had no additional information of the nature of that `const_void_ptr` I felt a `static_cast` was not a valid choice as it didn't feel "safe"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
const void* ptr = "test example";
auto ucharptr = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(ptr);

//to remove the const ness
unsigned char* test = const_cast<unsigned char*>(ucharptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would probably be the following:

```
unsigned char* ucharptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<void*>(const_void_ptr));
```

Comment: This doesn't work since reinterpret_cast cannot convert from const void* to a unsigned char*

Comment: @YePhIcK @BobBobby I oversaw the `const`, sry. Corrected it.

Comment: There was a correction since this response was written? it works now